# Android 2.3 enviar correo directo a GMail, Outlook, Yahoo

Tags: android, gmail, outlook

estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde hay usuarios registrados en una tabla de MySQL donde hay un campo "correo".

En la App, hay un botón "Olvidé mi contraseña", cuando el usuario haga clic, que reciba un "mensaje" con su contraseña en su correo con el cual está registrado.

El envío debe ser "automático", es decir, no debe pedir elegir un cliente de correos.

> Encontré muchos ejemplos pero como siempre, NO FUNCIONABAN por estar mal explicados, pero al fin encontré uno que SI FUNCIONA y quiero compartirlo con ustedes.

Artículo original: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/

Comment: ayuda no me funciona. Cuando ejecuto para Gmail me dice una excepcion que no se puede conectar al puerto 465, ya intente con 567. Cuando ejecuto para hotmail me dice que no puede convertir el socket a TLS.

Comment: @Angelica, verifica que haz añadido el permiso <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> en  AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Descargar las librerías JAR necesarias (mail.jar, additionnal.jar, activation.jar).
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9kauvwrzj1263x/librerias.rar?dl=0
2. Crear un proyecto vacío en Android.
3. En el explorador de proyectos, cambiar de "Android a Project"
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Copiar los 3 JAR y pegarlos en la carpeta "libs" haciendo clic derecho y luego en la opción "Paste".
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Hacer clic en el Menú "File" y luego en "Project Structure"
6. Se abrirá una ventana, haga clic en la opción "app", luego en la pestaña "Dependencies".
7. Hacer clic en el símbolo "+" y luego en la opción "JAR dependency" para agregar nueva librería.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
8. Se abrirá otra ventana, elegir las librerias que pegamos antes (una a una), hacer clic en OK.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
9. Cuando hayamos agregado las 3 librerias JAR, hacer clic en OK de la ventana "Proyect Structure".
10. Cambiar de "Project a Android" (ver paso 3).
11. Crear la clase **clsConfiguracion.java**

    ```
    public class clsConfiguracion {
        public static final String DE_CORREO ="remitente@dominio.com";
        public static final String DE_PASSWORD ="contraseña_remitente";
    }
    ```
12. Crear la clase **clsEnviaCorreo**

    ```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class clsEnviaCorreo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        private Context contexto;
        private Session De_Sesion;

        private String A_Correo;
        private String A_Asunto;
        private String A_Mensaje;

        private ProgressDialog progreso;

        public clsEnviaCorreo(Context cContexto, String cCorreo, String cAsunto, String cMensaje) {
            this.contexto = cContexto;
            this.A_Correo = cCorreo;
            this.A_Asunto = cAsunto;
            this.A_Mensaje = cMensaje;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progreso = ProgressDialog.show(contexto, "Enviando mensaje", "Espere...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progreso.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Mensaje enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            /*Configuraciones según el proveedor de Correo electrónico que enviará el Mensaje*/
            /*=========================================================================================
                                             PARA GMAIL
             Requisito: se debe activar "Permitir que aplicaciones menos seguras accedan a tu cuenta"
         https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
                ===========================================================================================*/
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            /*=========================================================================================
                                             PARA OUTLOOK (ANTES HOTMAIL)
        ===========================================================================================*/
            /*props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");*/
           /*=========================================================================================
                                             PARA YAHOO
             Requisito: se debe activar "Permitir aplicaciones que utilicen un inicio de sesión menos seguro"
             https://login.yahoo.com/account/security#other-apps?lang=es-ES
        ===========================================================================================*/
            /*props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");*/

            De_Sesion = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(clsConfiguracion.DE_CORREO, clsConfiguracion.DE_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    });

            try {
                MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(De_Sesion);
                mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(clsConfiguracion.DE_CORREO));
                mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(A_Correo));
                mm.setSubject(A_Asunto);
                mm.setText(A_Mensaje);
                Transport.send(mm);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    ```
13. **activity_main.xml**

    ```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCorreoDestino"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="correo_destino@gmail.com"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDestinatario"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAsunto"
        android:text="Asunto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCorreoDestino"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAsunto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prueba de mensaje"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblAsunto"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMensaje"
        android:text="Mensaje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAsunto"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="4"
        android:text="Este es un mensaje de prueba desde JavaMail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblMensaje"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
        android:text="Enviar correo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMensaje"/>
    ```
14. **MainActivity.java**

    ```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private EditText xCorreo;
        private EditText xAsunto;
        private EditText xMensaje;
        private Button xEnviar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            xCorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCorreoDestino);
            xAsunto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAsunto);
            xMensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
            xEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
            xEnviar.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        private void EnviarCorreo() {
            String sCorreo = xCorreo.getText().toString().trim();
            String sAsunto = xAsunto.getText().toString().trim();
            String sMensaje = xMensaje.getText().toString().trim();
            clsEnviaCorreo objCorreo = new clsEnviaCorreo(this, sCorreo, sAsunto, sMensaje);
            objCorreo.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EnviarCorreo();
        }
    }
    ```
15. Por último los permisos necesarios en **AndroidManifest.xml**

    ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    ```
16. Ahora sí, a probar y agradecer ;), suerte a todos.

> En el caso de GMAIL y YAHOO, se debe activar los permisos correspondientes para que pueda funcionar, (lea los comentarios dentro del código de **clsEnviaCorreo**.